# Window.print() showing weird characters, not printing custom fonts

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing, fonts

EDIT: I am just using a basic "window.print()" call, attached to a button on the page.

I have a site with some custom fonts, and when I try to print the page they show up as weird characters. This is what the print preview looks like:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: How do you load the fonts?  If its by CSS, did you include the CSS in your print CSS?

Comment: It is CSS. How do I include it in my print CSS? I've never had to do that before. I'm just using window.print()

Comment: Do you have special CSS rules for just printing?  Also, does it render fine on the webpage (before you print)?

Comment: Yes, it looks fine on the webpage, and I'm not sure what you mean about special CSS rules for printing, so I suppose I don't. Is there a way I can change the fonts to a websafe font just for printing?

Comment: Yes, you just change the font in your print CSS--either a special CSS sheet that loads only for printing, or a special set of rules alongside your default CSS.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Printing for more information.